# Align responsive content within a div

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

using FOUNDATION 6.

Have 3 columns, each has:

- image (always same size)
- title  (varies in length )
- text   (varies in length )
- button

How can I have them all align horizontally throughout the colums?

This is current situation:
[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TkyP.png)

What I need:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZHo.jpg)

Current code for this section:

```html
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-3  " data-equalizer="prodMain" >
    <div class="column" data-equalizer-watch="prodMain" >
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://img1.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/96123/captiva-beach-captiva_54_990x660_201404211817.jpg" />
        <h5>Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button tiny ">ABOUT THE LOREM</a>
    </div>            
    <div class="column" data-equalizer-watch="prodMain">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://img1.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/96123/captiva-beach-captiva_54_990x660_201404211817.jpg" />
        <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button tiny ">ABOUT THE LOREM Y</a>
    </div>      
    <div class="column" data-equalizer-watch="prodMain">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://img1.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/96123/captiva-beach-captiva_54_990x660_201404211817.jpg" />
        <h5>Lorem ipsum  & Lorem ipsum </h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button tiny ">ABOUT OUR LOREM</a>
    </div>
</div><!--/  -->
```

Comment: apply height to `title` and `text` , may be `min-height`

Comment: I thought about that, but then I might have allot of empty space.I also thought of some js solution, measuring the height of each title and then making them all the same height as tallest,  but this seems overkill.

Comment: then you need to use jQuery :D

Comment: but dostnt is sound like overkill to use js for this?

Comment: It is overkill, that's why min. `height` hack will do..

Comment: We sometimes use js for this when it is an eye-catching thing. For such basic purpose, we do CSS hacks. :D

Comment: Is this for a one-off use or dynamically generated titles where you don't know what the specific length will be?

Comment: dynamic.  content admin will enter whatever they want

Comment: Since foundation data-equalizer is js driven but isn't completely doing the job, why is a small extra js solution overkill if that's what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you could try including a class like same-height to your html, then testing with jquery

HTML (add the extra class name **same-height**)

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-3 same-height" data-equalizer="prodMain" >
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

    function getLargest(elements) {
      largest = 0;
      $(elements).each(function(i, obj) {
        if($(this).height() > largest) {
          largest = $(this).height();
        }
      });
      return largest;
    }

    function setHeights(elements, largest) {
      $(elements).each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).height(largest);
      });
    }

    var largest = getLargest('.same-height h5');
    setHeights('.same-height h5', largest);
    var largest = getLargest('.same-height p');
    setHeights('.same-height p', largest);

});
```

Works fine but if you want to resize the browser or limit to certain screen sizers you would need extra code.